# Extracting data using regexp_extract in Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, extract, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract data from a column which has multiple characters and I am only interested in getting the specific string from the input string. My sample input and outputs are as below. How can I implement this using regexp_extract function.Can someone share their thoughts on this if you have worked on GBQ.Thanks.

**

- SQL:-

**

```
   SELECT request.url AS url 
    FROM [xyz.abc]
    WHERE regexp_extract(input,r'he=(.{32})')
```

**

- Input:-

**

```
http://mpp.xyz.com/conv/v=5;m=1;t=16901;ts=20150516234355;he=5e3152eafc50ed0346df7f10095d07c4;catname=Horoscope  
2   http://mpp.xyz.com/conv/v=5;m=1;t=16901;ts=20150516234335;he=5e3152eafc50ed0346df7f10095d07c4;catname=High+Speed+Internet
```

**

- Output :-

**
**

```
5e3152eafc50ed0346df7f10095d07c4
5e3152eafc50ed0346df7f10095d07c4
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple to do:

```
select regexp_extract(input,r'he=(.{32})');
```

or as example:

```
select regexp_extract('http://mpp.xyz.com/conv/v=5;m=1;t=16901;ts=20150516234355;he=5e3152eafc50ed0346df7f10095d07c4;catname=Horoscope',r'he=(.{32})')
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Pentium. But I get this error when I run the same. Argument type mismatch in function LOGICAL_AND: first argument is type bool, second argument is type string

Comment: You should check your data types, these work with STRING columns. Share your query if you still have issue to be able to help.

Comment: That's a confused SQL, you cannot use this way the REGEXP as where. `SELECT regexp_extract(request.url,r'he=(.{32})')  as output AS url 
    FROM [xyz.abc]`

Comment: My bad... I removed it from where clause and tried running keeping it in SELECT clause... but it is returning me NULLs.

Comment: What does .{32} mean?