# Regular Expression to extract a string based on delimiter

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract a substring from a string based on delimiter '.'(period). Can someone share your thoughts on how to do it using regexp_extract please. Thanks.

**

```
- Input:-

15.075
0.035
```

**

```
Output
075
035
```

Answer (score 2):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333484/extracting-data-using-regexp-extract-in-google-bigquery), it appears that you can use parentheses to capture of the match, as you would in most regex systems. That is, match the whole ".[0-9]+", but only capture the numeric portion, by surrounding it with parentheses, like this:

```
select regexp_extract(input, r'\.([0-9]+)');
```

This says to match a period followed by one or more numbers, and to extract the numeric portion only. I think that the leading `r` marks that string as a regular expression, but I can't find documentation on it.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en#regularexpressionfunctions

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you will want to use [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en)

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(number, r'\.(\d+)')
```

Comment: Thank u.. how do i get the first part of the string.. like if it is 15.075 I am looking for 15.